# Cocoa: Button Control in secondary .xib (loaded from MainWindowController) fails to invoke its Action

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

A simple test application using Xcode 7.3 under MacOs 10.10 using objective c.

```
AppDelegate.h
    @property MainWindowController *myMainWindowController;

AppDelegate.m
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    _myMainWindowController = [[MainWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindowController"];

    [_myMainWindowController showWindow:self];
}
```

The MainWindowController.xib is just MainWindow with a Main View

```
MainWindowController.h
    @property IBOutlet NSView * mainView;  //hooked up to the View in the MainWindowController.xib

MainWindowController.m
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    MyXib* vc = [[MyXib alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [_mainView addSubview:[vc view] ];
}
```

MyXib was created in Xcode as a subclass of NSViewController. It has a Button object, in its View.

MyXib.h

```
@interface MyXib : NSViewController
- (IBAction)buttonPushed:(id)sender;
```

MyXib.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPushed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"buttonPushed");
}
```

The the action for the theButton is connected to buttonPushed.

When running the application, the user interface is displayed as expected. But when the Button is clicked, the program crashes without ever invoking the buttonPushed method. Sometimes the debug window shows a stack crawl ending with something like "[NSURL buttonPushed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.."

I have put in calls to viewDidLoad, awakeFromNib, and init. Break points in these calls seem to show things behaving logically according to documentation.

Comment: Nothing is holding on to the viewcontroller and it is deallocated.

Comment: What is the simplest way to keep it from being de-allocated?

Comment: Add a property `MyXib* vc` in MainWindowController.m.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Willeke! Here is the fix to maintain a reference:

```
#import "MainWindowController.h"

@interface MainWindowController ()
@property IBOutlet NSView * mainView;
@property  MyXib* vc; // maintain a reference!

@end

@implementation MainWindowController

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    //create an NSViewController and use it to load the xib
    _vc = [MyXib alloc];
    _vc = [_vc initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [_mainView addSubview:[_vc view] ];
}

@end
```